# Скачивание файла из сайта через кэш

Tags: php

Как сделать скачивание как на mega.nz на своем сайте
Сперва в кэш браузера и после сохранить в комп
https://mega.nz/file/NwlR1QCZ#d25BPoprBp3x4hLCZd7eC_aXeMUsa9htegAfeWnzXMk

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот тут если нажать скачать сперва скачивается в кэш браузера потом сохраняется как обычное скачивание
https://mega.nz/file/NwlR1QCZ#d25BPoprBp3x4hLCZd7eC_aXeMUsa9htegAfeWnzXMk

как на скриншоте
https://prnt.sc/226md0l

И после уже сохраняется
https://prnt.sc/226mfoc